# How to submit Arabic applications to app store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I'm a swift application developer and I don't have a good experience in publishing applications to app store. I have created a tabbed view application in Xcode 6 Using Swift with Arabic / Persian content, now I want to submit this application to the iOS App Store in iTunes Connect. In iTunes Connect, I added the screen shots and app Descriptions, now when I'm saving and clicking on the submit to review,  there is a problem with the language of my app. I set that to English, I want to set the language to Arabic, but I can't see that language in the list.

How can I set the language to Arabic?

Answer (score 3):

Okey, Just set the language of your app as English and on iTunes connect while creating the app choose English. then fill your app name in Arabic and if your app has Arabic content just keep it. just upload to the store and it should work fine.

**Note :** You cannot select Arabic in Xcode or iTunes connect. just do as i said !

Answer (score 0):

[image]Latest update on this question:

Now with the release of iOS 13, App store connect has supported 40 different languages including Arabic. So while submitting an app version, we can select languages to localize and add content like App Name, Description, Privacy policy url for each language and submit to app store. We can also choose one language as Primary language as well. The languages will be shown in app store as follows:

For example, if the primary language you select for your app in App Store Connect is English and it’s the only language you provide, your app metadata(Name, Description,Url, Whats new) in all App Store territories appears in English. If you localize your app metadata in Arabic, users whose language setting is Arabic will see the Arabic localization of meta Data. Users in territories where the App Store supports Arabic but not English also see the Arabic localization. Users can search for your app using localized keywords in all territories where the App Store supports Arabic. If there’s no localization available that matches the language setting, the next most relevant localization is used. In other App Store territories, users see your metadata in the primary language (English in this example).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Fix is below. You can see English right side-> select Arabic/your language there and add date for What's new in this version. You can save and click Add for Review.

[image]